# Major advantages and disadvantages in using  <?php  , <?   ,<script language=“php”> , <%  in php

Tags: php, tags

hi i saw there are four types of tags using in php .

```
<?php

?>
```

and

```
<?

?>
```

and

```
<script language=“php”>

</script>
```

and

```
<%

%>
```

and only the first one is using and others are deprecated .

i want to know the major advantages and disadvantages of each . and want to know why the 2 ,3 ,4 ones are deprecated .

Comment: There's no advantages to using deprecated features... sooner or later you'll probably trip over an issue using them. The second example is probably the most widely used outside of the first, and migrate a script with short tags to a server where they're disabled is a pain. » http://stackoverflow.com/questions/200640/are-php-short-tags-acceptable-to-use

Comment: Use `<?php` and stop worrying.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Normal **php tags**
2. XML tags
3. HTML tags
4. ASP tags

I think the disadvantage of deprecated tags is that they are common in other languages too, not only php.

Answer (score 0):

They are going to be deprecated in php6

Because these php short tags are not supported on all servers

Comment: I assume you mean PHP 7, as there is no PHP 6

Comment: When this answer was posted, PHP7 was not released and the next probable version to come out was v6