# Difference between <?php ?> and <script language="php"></script>

Tags: php

I was simply going through the tutorial of PHP there I found that we can write our PHP code using `<script language="php"></script>` tag also, and I was trying to figure out the difference between this and `<?php ?>` tag and advantages or disadvantages but didn't found anything, can anyone tell me the difference please.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Major advantages and disadvantages in using <?php , <? ,<script language=“php”> , <% in php](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6909303/major-advantages-and-disadvantages-in-using-php-script-language-ph)

Comment: @BoltClock'saUnicorn except the accepted answer isn't very accurate.

Comment: @yahelc: Yeah... [php] really needs better answers.

Comment: thanks for the reply, same thing was running in my mind to, but I was thinking might be there is any difference, but by looking all the answers I guess there is not.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I think, in terms of semantics there is no advantages or disadvantages. According to [PHP manual](http://php.net/manual/en/language.basic-syntax.phpmode.php):

> There are four different pairs of opening and closing tags which can
>   be used in PHP. Two of those, `<?php ?>` and `<script language="php"></script>`, are **always available**.

Also, note that:

> If you are embedding PHP within XML or XHTML you will need to use the
>   `<?php ?>` tags to remain compliant with standards.

Anyway, the `<?php ?>` is the most commonly used and recommended to use it.

**NOTE**: Script tags `<script language="php"></script>` and ASP tags `<% %>` are removed from PHP 7.

Answer (score 4):

They both work <sub>(much to my surprise)</sub>.

However, `<?php ?>` is by far the most common construction. You're much more likely to confuse fellow coders if you use the very rare deprecated `<script>` method.

As a result, you should use `<?php ?>` merely to avoid confusion or potential compatibility problems across implementations.

Answer (score 0):

Always use `<?php ?>` because its default and works on every configuration. Other scopes may not be open from php configuration. And they will deprecate

Answer (score 0):

I decided to use `<?php` because I experienced some problems using the popular phpStorm IDE. It does not support `<script>`. Neither syntax highlighting nor line breaks point work using the `<script>` method. Maybe this information is useful for someone else too.